# UML ERD Database modelling Query

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

I have the following tables in my database.

1. (Member) is assigned to 1.m facility
2. (Facility) has assigned 1.m member
3. (Facility) enrolled to 1.m program
4. (Program) enrolls 1.m facility

I want to query all member facilities that are not enrolled in a program.

Should there be a direct link between (nacmemberfacility) and (nacFacilityProgram)?

Can two intersecting entities be linked?

What is code for this query?

[image]

Comment: UML or ERD ?   It's not the same thing.  And what kind of quarry ?  OCL,  SQL,  plaintext?

Comment: SQL or plain text

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. How are you 1st stuck/unsure answering it? What presentation of what DB design method? PS An ERD is an image of DDL. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] Please do not ask us to write your code for you. PS what are "direct link" & "intersecting entities"? PS FK & other constraints ("links" [sic]) need not hold, be known or be declared in order to query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Member` - `Facility` is a many-to-many relationship according to your narrative.  In your diagram you have decomposed it into two one-to-many relationships `Member` - `MemberFacility` - `Facility`  (the diagram is wrong in this regard).   Note that the "many" side is on the wrong side in both cases.

Same for `Facility` - `Program` which you transformed into `Facility` - `FacilityProgram` - `Program`

If you want to find out all the `MemberFacility` that are not enrolled in a `Program`, you do not need a direct relationship between `MemberFacility` and `Program` since you may deduce it from the existing relationships:

```
select * from MemberFacility 
   where facilityId not in (select facilityId from MemberProgram);
```

You would need the direct relationship only if individual members of a facility would or would not participate to the program a facility is enrolled in.

Comment: @DavidGarcia it is always possible to create a relationship. The issue is that if it's redudant, it'll be cumbersome to keep it in sync.